# The difference between vertical and horizontal orientation about layout_gravity and gravity

Tags: android, gravity, layout-gravity

I have a TextView in a LinearLayout.

I want to try different modes for layout_gravity and gravity.

I have this code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#A55C93"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#005Cff"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textSize="21sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I have `android:orientation="vertical"`, everything about `layout_gravity` and `gravity` makes sense. But when I have `android:orientation="horizontal"`, outputs are different from the first, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to understand is that `layout_gravity` on a child view is an attribute that communicates "up" to the parent, and "asks" the parent to behave in a certain way.

In this case, the parent is a `LinearLayout`, which has a different attribute (`orientation`) that already affects the positioning of child views. Therefore, when a child specifies `layout_gravity`, what happens depends on the `LinearLayout`'s `orientation`.

- For a `horizontal` LinearLayout, any horizontal component of the child's `layout_gravity` is ignored.
- For a `vertical` LinearLayout, any vertical component of the child's `layout_gravity` is ignored.

You're using `center`, which is basically `center_vertical` + `center_horizontal`. So for a horizontal LinearLayout, the horizontal centering will be ignored. And, for a vertical LinearLayout, the vertical centering will be ignored.

Given that your example only has one child view, you could consider replacing the parent `LinearLayout` with a `FrameLayout`. Then the child `layout_gravity` will be fully respected.

Answer (score 1):

try this code and you will see the difference
increase your layout height to see the difference; it will help you understand the flow better

when you set gravity center to a horizantal linear layout the center does not refer to center horizantal, it refers to center vertically.

i know it sounds confusing but try this code and you will have a better idea of what im trying to say.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:background="#A55C93"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="#005Cff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

also try this with vertical

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="500dp"
android:background="#A55C93"
android:orientation="vertical"
  tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"

  >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:background="#005Cff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:text="text"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

try adding multiple views to the layout and it will help you give a precise idea.
**in other terms in a horizantally oriented linear layout if you set layout gravity center is will align your view at center of height of Linear layout and if you set layout gravity center to a vertically aligned linear layout it will align your view center to the width of linear layout**